# Show that the point satisfies the conditions

Tags: calculus, coordinate-systems

A round membrane in space, is over the space $x^2+y^2 \leq a^2$.

The maximum coordinate $z$ of a point of the membrane is $b$.

We suppose that $(x, y, z)$ is a point of the inclined membrane.

Show that the respective point $(r , \theta , z)$ in cylindrical coordinates satisfies the conditions $$0 \leq r \leq a \ , \ \ 0 \leq \theta \leq 2 \pi  \ , \ \ |z| \leq b$$

$$$$

Could you give me some hints how we could show that??

$$$$

**EDIT:**

Using cylindrical coordinates we get $r=\sqrt{x^2+y^2}=\leq |a|$ and sonve $r \geq 0$ we have $0 \leq r \leq a$.

From the defintion of cylindrincal coordinates we have that $0 \leq \theta \leq 2 \pi$,

But how do we get that $|z| \leq b$?? By the sentence "The maximum coordinate $z$ of a point of the membrane is $b$" ??

Comment: You have a typo:  your conditions should be $0 \le \rho \le a$.  Plot your condition $x^2 + y^2 \le a^2$ on a graph and then draw a line segment from the origin labelled $\rho$ at an angle $\theta$ with respect to the $x$ axis.  All should be clear then.

Comment: I had a typo at the point... It should be $(r, \theta , z)$ and not $(\rho , \theta , z)$... @DavidG.Stork 

Is using a graph the only way to show it??

Comment: Taking two minutes to graph it will make the answer obvious, I believe.  It is by far the simplest way.

Comment: Use spherical coordinates to help you: i.e. $x=r\cos\theta$,$y=r\sin\theta$.

Comment: Using spherical coordinates we get $$x^2+y^2 \leq a^2 \Rightarrow r^2 \leq a^2 \Rightarrow 0 \leq r \leq a$$ 

How can we get the other conditions?? 

$$$$

Why do we have to use spherical coordinates?? @freak_warrior